# Where is the compiled webapp when running a web application through Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am building a web application using Intellij IDEA. I use Tomcat run configuration in IDEA to run the webapp.

What is the location of the compiled webapp which gets pointed to tomcat? How does IDEA point out tomcat where the compiled webapp is? (The .war file or extracted directory inside `webapps` directory in tomcat installation doesn't change when I do changes and run).

Tomcat prints the environment variables it uses at startup (`CATALINA_BASE`, `CATALINA_HOME` etc.). But none of those locations contained the compiled webapp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the artifacts you want to the deploy to Tomcat in the **Deployment** tab, which is located in your Tomcat Server configuration.

From the IntelliJ help:

> Deployment tab
>
> Use this tab to specify which artifacts and/or external resources
> should be deployed onto the server. (An external resource means a
> deployable Web component such as a .war file which is not represented
> by a project artifact. Usually, such components are stored outside of
> the project scope.)

Comment: Actually my question is how IDEA points out tomcat where the artifact is, and the location where IDEA puts the artifact. Not how to configure tomcat run configuration in IDEA.

Comment: It will deploy your war to the CATALINA_BASE directory, which is located under your IntelliJ user dir, for instance in Windows: "C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_app_2

Comment: As I described in the question, I checked `CATALINA_BASE` directory which tomcat printed at startup. It only contained `conf`, `logs` and `work` directories. No webapp found in that location.

Comment: Normally it unpacks the war under 

.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_app_2\work\Catalina\localhost\_\WEB-INF